# Asking the same question for WP8 - post a bounty, or separate question?

Tags: discussion

> Topic in question:  [Is it possible to "root" a Windows Phone device? What are the benefits?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/17/is-it-possible-to-root-a-windows-phone-device-what-are-the-benefits)

The question here is very general, but the given answer is only addressing Windows Phone 7.  Should I post a separate question for Windows Phone 8, or just post a bounty to this one?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case I think is better separate this two things. Maybe rename the old one too.